# Reactjs combine all the states to parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component which has three child components which needs to pass the child states to its parent components so that the submit button can passon the info with all the user selected info. All the html elements are generated through JSON.

Please find my parent component below:

```
class ScreenField extends Component {
    bindNewState(newState) {
        //this.setState([...this.state,newState]) -- Not Working
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <InputField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={(newState) => this.bindNewState(newState)}/>
                <LabelField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={(newState) => this.bindNewState(newState)}/>
                <RadioField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={(newState) => this.bindNewState(newState)}/>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

So my bindNewState method should combine all the states that is passed through its child components. Unable to know how to do that??
Complete code is at the [URL](https://github.com/yvsivateja/ReactJSApplications/blob/one/React-json-render/components/ScreenField.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding is not working, you can do bind `bindNewState` like this `this.bindNewState.bind(this)`. This way, the scope of your parent component is kept. You final code will looks like this:

```
class ScreenField extends Component {
    bindNewState(newState) {
        //this.setState([...this.state,newState]) -- Not Working
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <InputField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState.bind(this)}/>
                <LabelField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState.bind(this)}/>
                <RadioField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState.bind(this)}/>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

Or since it's the same method, you bind bind it in the constructor like this:

```
class ScreenField extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.bindNewState = this.bindNewState.bind(this);
    }

    bindNewState(newState) {
        //this.setState([...this.state,newState]) -- Not Working
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                <InputField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState}/>
                <LabelField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState}/>
                <RadioField screenField={this.props.screenField} handleStateChange={this.bindNewState}/>
            </span>
        )
    }
}
```

Don't forget to pass props in `super()` if you bind your method in the constructor.

Comment: how do I have the newState changed in such case, as my state keeps on changing whenever user enters a character in each of the child components

Comment: My method is being called from its child components, but the issue here is i need to combine all my child component dynamic element states to its parent component(ScreenField) state

Comment: In your child component, you need to call `this.props. handleStateChange ` with the object that will be pass as parameter to `bindNewState`.

Comment: yes it is being called and when I try to pring newState in bindNewState method... it is working as expected... now I have other components which calls the same method, so I want to combine the previous State with current state

Comment: You should then keep a track of each child state in the parent component. You can update your state like so `this.setState({ childOne: newState })`; You can do this for all of your children component. You can have one method per child component in this case.

Comment: How do I do that... All the elements generated in my child are dynamic... If possible can you please take a look at my code given in the URL at original question probably you might get an idea of where I'm stuck

Comment: In this case, why not having one state per child component? If you can't keep track of your childComponent states inside your parent state, it will be really hard to have proper data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138415/discussion-between-pathfinder-and-vincent-damour).

Answer (score 0):

It seems `bindNewState` method is not bound to `ScreenField` class. do this in the constractor

```
class ScreenField extends React.Component {

 constructor(){
    super()
    this.bindNewState = this.bindNewState.bind(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: My method is being called from its child components, but the issue here is i need to combine all my child component dynamic element states to its parent component(ScreenField) state